# Why does the rebellious son receive the harshest form of capital punishment?

Tags: ben-sorer-umoreh

The Gemara says that the reason why the Ben Sorer is killed is in order to prevent him from sinning in the future.

Question: if it is only a prevention, and not because of something he already did, then why does he get stoned - the harshest of the four capital punishments?

And if it is a Gezairas Hakasuv, then he seemingly should not be buried together with others who were stoned - are there any commentators who say so?

Comment: Great question! Especially since one explanation is that he will definitely come to murder- but even murderers are "only" punished with beheading. So _kal v'chomer_ a Ben sorer...

Answer (score 1):

This questions your assumption, but does not answer your question.

The Gemara in Sanhedrin 72a does quote Rabbi Yosei as saying the rebellious son should die while he is "still innocent" because he will do bad things in the future.  But that is a minority opinion.  The rest of the sources say clearly that Judaism does not punish preemptively.  For example, when Abraham chased away Ishmael and his mother Hagar, they were dying of thirst in the desert, but God opened up a well for them. The Torah says:

> God has heard the voice of the lad where he is. [Gen. 21:17]

The Talmud interprets “where he is” as follows:

> Rabbi Yitzhaq further said: Man is judged only according to his actions up to the time of judgment. [Rosh Hashanah 16b]

The Midrash adds:

> Rabbi Simon said: The ministering angels… exclaimed:  “Lord of the universe, will you bring up a well for [Ishmael], who will one day slay your children with thirst?” God asked them: “At this moment, what is he?” “Righteous,” they replied. [God answered:] “I judge man only as he is at the moment.” [Gen. R. 53:14]

Besides, everyone can repent (do teshuva) and thereby be redeemed.  The psalmist writes:  Though my father and my mother have rejected me, the Lord will receive me. [Ps. 27:10]

Comment: The answer they give to the difference between Ben Sorrer and Yishmael is that by the Ben Sorrer, it’s him himself who will be doing the future sin so therefore we can kill him to stop himself. But by Yishmael, his “future evil” is committed by his descendants, so in that case it wouldn’t be right to punish Yishmael for something his distant descendants will do